# Camille Jordan : Treatise on substitutions and algebraic equations ??

Tags: reference-works

Is there english translation available of the monograph by Camille Jordan, titled: Traité des substitutions et des équations algébriques, which is available easily online in french.

The reason for asking is that the english title of the monograph is referenced so much in literature, that felt there must be a translation but none I could found in-spite of all efforts. So, thought it better to ask.

Comment: I also didn't find any, not even print versions in classic libraries. However, in 1870, French was a major scientific language and many mathematicians were proficient in reading and writing in French. It is therefore very likely that Jordan's book was never actually translated, as there was no need.

Comment: I put up a bounty of +300 on this question to give it more attention. Unfortunately, there were zero answers. Nonetheless, I lose the 300 points—they simply disappear into the aether.  What the actual f? No good deed goes unpunished, I guess. Would have never done that if I'd read the fine print. Buyer beware!

Answer (score 2):

There is a very partial translation of Book IV in Jeremy Gray's *History of Abstract Algebra* (Springer). See Chapter 13, and Appendix D.